# Video/Image Processing in Xamarin

Tags: android, image-processing, xamarin, video-processing

I need some guidance. I want to load a video in Xamarin.Android app and access each frame of the video and overlay some text/another image on the selected frame and replace it with the selected frame. 
Can someone please tell me how can I do this kind of video processing in Xamarin.Android?

Comment: Try to first show some effort you have done till now by posting the code !

Comment: @utkarshdubey there is no official component available for xamarin video.. Then how can he some effort or try?
Are you Xamarin developer?

Comment: check this link.. they refer some 3rd party library for video.. It may be helpful
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/74126/how-to-play-a-video-in-xamarin-forms-its-possible#latest

Comment: @utkarshdubey I have not done any effort yet as still try to get the info.

Comment: @RanjithKumar I tried the link but sorry It is not as useful as I expected

Comment: what you expected? and what not available in this library?

Comment: I need a library to access a frame of video, and want to do some image processing on it.